# Schwarz inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So Schwarz inequality states that

$$|a^Tb|\leq||a||\cdot||b||$$

since $\cos (x)$ is always between $-1$ and $1$, I get this part. 
But the question seems confusing, I couldn't find a way to turn it into the format stated above.

> Question : By choosing the correct vector $b$ in the Schwarz
>   inequality, prove that
>
> $$(a_1+a_2+a_3+...+a_n)^2\leq n(a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^3+...+a_n^2)$$ When
>   does the equality hold?

So first of all I tried choosing $n$, the right side of the equation is equal to

$$a^Ta$$

but I couldn't figure what the left side of the equation is equal to, and how am I suppose to chose the $n$? Will I make up a vector or is n going to be something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

Take $a=(a_1,...,a_n)$ and $b=(1,...,1)$ and then use Cauchy Schwarz.

Notice that $$|a^Tb|\leq \|a\|\|b\|\iff |a^Tb|^2\leq \|a\|^2\|b\|^2.$$